# How do I know if an R package is commonly used?

Tags: r, r-package

I am somewhat new to R and should certainly be considered an amateur in data analysis. I am thoroughly impressed by the sheer number of packages available for data wrangling and analysis in R. However, I often find that multiple packages will do the same things. My fundamental question is about how to decide which package to use (if any), but this of course highly specific and to some extent very subjective (e.g. tidyverse vs base R).

A proxy for this question is about how to know if a package is commonly used, which could serve as an indirect indicator of it's usefulness.

I did try and get an overview by looking for citations in academic papers and various GitHub-metrics, but find it tedious and imprecise. Further, not all packages are on GitHub. It would be very useful to have an overview like the CRAN Task View that includes number of downloads/package citations or similar. Are such metrics available anywhere?

I understand that this question is borderline appropriate for the SO-community. I happily take suggestions for more appropriate communities.

Comment: Have a look at `library(cranlogs)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package `cranlogs` to get download statistics and compare the popularity (or a proxy of it) of the different alternatives available for a particular tasks.

https://github.com/r-hub/cranlogs

e.g. as of today these are the most downloaded packages during last week

```r
> cranlogs::cran_top_downloads("last-week")
   rank     package  count       from         to
1     1       rlang 594334 2023-02-02 2023-02-08
2     2         cli 580335 2023-02-02 2023-02-08
3     3     ggplot2 578947 2023-02-02 2023-02-08
4     4       vctrs 554676 2023-02-02 2023-02-08
5     5   lifecycle 513724 2023-02-02 2023-02-08
6     6       dplyr 430810 2023-02-02 2023-02-08
7     7        ragg 390004 2023-02-02 2023-02-08
8     8 textshaping 379241 2023-02-02 2023-02-08
9     9  tidyselect 329511 2023-02-02 2023-02-08
10   10    devtools 307863 2023-02-02 2023-02-08
```